# Send email using Microsoft Graph API from shared mailbox using azure logic app

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity

This seems like it should be incredibly easy. But here I am on day 3 of reading blogs and watching youtube videos from India. Is this just not possible?

I have a LogicApp that has a system assigned identity. I used Powershell to create an identity in Exchange online based off of this identity and give the "Send As" permission to a shared mailbox. That part is done and I didn't get any errors and we've done the same thing for "actual code" projects that use "App Registrations" and the Microsoft.Graph library to send emails so I'm fairly confident it works.

I can't use an O365 connector in the LogicApp because that needs a user to login and create the connection. Then I'd have to give myself rights to "Send As" this mailbox which I don't want to do and seems like a terrible practice because one day I might leave the company, probably by stroke, but still my account might one day be gone.

Using the [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) I can see that mail can be sent using the graph in what seems like a pretty straight forward way. I've verified, using the graph explorer that I can send mail as myself using that API.

Can I send email as a shared mailbox via the Microsoft Graph API using an Azure LogicApp? Even if I need to create an App Registration to do it, that's fine. I don't know how to tell the API to send send an email using a system assigned identity.

Comment: Instead of your own account, could you not use a service type user?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Skin, you can use service account for authentication instead of user login.
I would suggest you to follow below steps, it may helps in achieving your requirement.

1. Create app registration for the logic app in active directory.
   [image]
2. Use system managed identity as authentication for graph api.
3. Refer this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/grant-graph-api-permission-to-managed-identity-object/ba-p/2792127#:%7E:text=Managed%20identities%20provide%20an%20identity%20for%20applications%20to,principal%20object%20in%20Azure%20or%20using%20Managed%20Identity.) for managed identity for graph API.
4. Grant system-assigned identity of logic app as **Send AS** permission for shared mailbox.
5. In logic app send email action, use shared mailbox address

```
I don't know how to tell the API to send send an email using a system assigned identity.
```

There is no need to specify the system-assigned identity in the API call. **When you use a system-assigned managed identity as authenticate with the Microsoft Graph API in your Logic App Http action, the identity is automatically passed to the API as part of the authentication process.**

- As shown in below image you can on System assigned identity in logic App.
  [image]
  Then in Http action take Post as method and mention Graph Api's URL and take managed identity as Authentication.
  [image]

Comment: Thank you for the resonse, the URI that's covered up combined with any headers and the Audience is mostly the part I'm struggling with. I turned on the Identity for the logic app and gave it permissions in the graph api to send mail and gave it permission to send as in exchange online, but what should the request look like?

Comment: URI for the API request will be the endpoint for the Microsoft Graph API's send mail function, it is  in the format of https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail.
In addition to the URI, you need to include the necessary headers for the request, such as the "Content-Type" and "Authorization" headers. The "Content-Type" header should be  "application/json" and the "Authorization" header should contain the token generated by the logic app's system-assigned managed identity.

Comment: I used the URI graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/user@domain.com/sendMail and it worked. The user being the email that we gave the Identity rights to in azure and in exchange. Thanks vijaya

Answer (score 0):

For me it is no more possible (by default) to send email with a shared email box, you have to use the same email than the one used to authenticate the account.